# Azure App Service Workaround 500 custom domain Limit

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans, azure-app-service-envrmnt

Is there any way to work around the 500 custom domain limit? This is horrible for SAAS companies for obvious reasons.

Is there any way to tell the Azure app service to respond to *.domain.com like you can with IIS?

Is my only other option to put Application gateway infront of it and run it in Azure Container Services or K8s?

Thanks!

Comment: There are some service limits that can be lifted if you contact Azure Support and ask them. That would be my only suggestion.

Comment: Why not take another approach to your tenant identifier? I assume they log in and acquire a token, why not have information in the token regarding the tenant identifier? This way 1 domain can serve all your customers and is hidden from them entirely.

Comment: For political and marketing reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is to setup a *.domain.com wildcard DNS CName record that points to your App Service address (you can do this with an A record instead if you want) and then add *.domain.com as a Custom Domain into the App Service.

Then you can bind a wildcard *.domain.com Certificate to it and you're golden. No limit.

Comment: Sadly, I need to be able to handle many unique domains (not simply subdomains). Is there a known workaround for that scenario besides spinning up multiple app instances?

Comment: Not that I found. Might try a support ticket to up the limit. I bailed and moved it all into kubernetes.

Comment: I was able to solve this by using an azure container instance which exposes a fully qualified domain name such as "http://customlabel.azureregion.azurecontainer.io". I then created a CNAME record that directed my domain to that FQDN

You could also use a VM but that was out of the question for us because of the overhead from a security auditing perspective.

Comment: Hi @Crhistian - what did you run in the container to forward the requests on to the backend website?  Or did you run the website in the container itself?

Comment: Websites were hosted separately. I had two containers deployed in my container group: nginx and a .net core webapp. Nginx which was basically a forward proxy which forwarded all requests to my webapp. The webapp had some business logic to determine where to redirect the requests